# Can I use the word "lead" in this way?

Tags: grammar

I will lead you to look around the museum.

Can "lead" take its object as infinitive ?

Comment: Yes, it can. However, the phrasing you use is a little stiff. 'I will lead you around the museum' comes across more naturally.

Comment: @Sam I'd say, "I'll show you through the museum." https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=%22show+you+through+the+museum%22&oq=%22show+you+through+the+museum%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...26169.41189.0.41622.30.30.0.0.0.0.509.6065.0j6j11j4j1j1.23.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..7.17.4201.0.h2gRy2FFYnU

Comment: You would usually only use "lead" with someone who needed extra help to navigate around, such as a blind person or perhaps a group of tourists (someone who needs a leader, basically).

Comment: If I heard the example sentence, I would take "lead" in the sense of: "I will induce you to look around the museum".

Comment: Here are a couple of other examples of lead with an infinitive.   "You lead me to believe I'd get the job." "It leads me to think you lied to me."

Answer (score 2):

From [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/learner/lead):

> **5** [transitive] to be the reason why somebody does or thinks something
>
> **lead somebody to do something**
>
> *This has led scientists to speculate on the existence of other galaxies.*

As stated above, one of the usages of *lead* is in transitive form and means "to be the reason why somebody does or thinks something".

So the meaning of the sentence is: The reason for speculating on the existence of other galaxies is "this". "This" refers to the previous sentence in the text that the reader had previously studied.

So in my point of view as there is not any causative relationship between "looking around the museum" and previous part of your sentence, it is better not to use "I will lead you to look around the museum."

Comment: Hello, Alireza Talebian, and thanks for your contribution to English Language & Usage. The answer you provided is useful and on point. I edited it to format the quoted language as a block quote and to link to the online dictionary you are quoting. At EL&U we make a serious effort to include such elements (especially linked citations to the sources of quoted language) in our answers. Thanks again.